# Related to legends for subplots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, legend, subplot, legend-properties

[I have created the 4 subplots with the legends showing on right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOiOV.jpg)When I create subplots in plotly , legends are created either in right side or in the bottom of all subplots. But how can I get legends right below the plot for every subplot.

I have tried with legendgroup. But its only groups all the legends related to that graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Orientation](https://plotly.com/python/v3/horizontal-legend/).

```py
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    y=-0.2             # Override the y distance to gain more or less space
))
```

[image: Result of orientation]

You can also use [Legend Positioning](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#legend-positioning) to your advantage.

```py
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="bottom",  # Anchor to the bottom
    y=-0.75,           # Override the y distance to move further down
    x=0.5              # Center in x if you wish
))
```

[image]